# Can I use a Linux PC as a MIDI router?

Tags: midi, linux

Using an Arturia Minilab (USB out only), I can control a Korg Volca (MIDI in only) using a Tie Studio 1|1 MIDI-USB adapter via LMMS (by setting up any instrument in LMMS and routing MIDI-in & MIDI-out appropriately; The instrument isn't used except to perform the routing).

I also know that I can do the same thing by using (eg) a Kenton USB-MIDI router, or, I assume, by using pretty much any DAW.

What I want to know is whether I can do this without either a DAW or any other hardware device other than the USB-MIDI adapter: Can I use my Linux laptop as a "MIDI software router"? If so, what do I need to do?

I'm using Puppy Linux "Bionic" 64-bit. ALSA. Jack is installed.

Comment: @cl solution works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linux kernel itself can route messages between MIDI ports. Such a connection is called a subscription, and applications must use it to get MIDI messages from the hardware port to their own port.

You can control connections with the [aconnect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/aconnect) tool. Run `aconnect -lio` to show a list of all ports and their current connections, and something like `aconnect 12:0 34:0` to connect the first ports on two devices.